# Extending the Django user model with a __getattr__ method

Tags: python, django

In a Django project, I have a module which extends Django's user model, similar to the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

User.add_to_class('__str__', __str__)
```

I've noticed that this works. However, if I try to define a `__getattr__` method, like so:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if self.user_profile:
        return getattr(self.user_profile, attr)
    else:
        raise AttributeError(f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' has no attribute '{attr}'")
```

I get the following error upon importing the module:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/lucy_web/models/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .user import User
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
TypeError: __getattr__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attr'
```

Is it not possible to extend the `User` model with a `__getattr__` method in this way?

Comment: It seems to do something weird and unexpected with cpython's import machinery. [There's an interesting code comment in that _handle_fromlist function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.7, if you define a module level function called `__getattr__` [it will be a module level attribute getter function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/), similar to a class getattr. Seems like you did that unintentionally. The module level `__getattr__` has a different call signature from the class method.

> #### Specification
>
> The `__getattr__` function at the module level should
>   accept one argument which is the name of an attribute and return the
>   computed value or raise an AttributeError:
>
> ```
> def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...
> ```

Try renaming the function to something else, to avoid unintentionally shadowing a reserved function name.

```
def  user_getattr(self, attr):
    ...

User.add_to_class('__getattr__', user_getattr)
```

[This is mentioned in PEP 562:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/#backwards-compatibility-and-impact-on-performance)

> This PEP may break code that uses module level (global) names
>   `__getattr__` and `__dir__`. (But the language reference explicitly reserves all undocumented dunder names, and allows "breakage without
>   warning")

[And here's what the language reference says:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)

> Any use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow
>   explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

So you should also rename your custom `__str__` function to avoid potential future breakage.